# Pgfplotstable using longtabu

Tags: pgfplotstable, longtabu

I need to typeset multiple tables from .csv data files in relatively complex document. I'm using pgfplotstable/longtable (resp. longtabu) combo and everithing works fine except some special (very rare in practice) circumstances: sometimes the table header is duplicated on a new page (and in addition separate top rule on previous page):
[image]

There is MWE for this (wrong case):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable, tabu, makecell}

\pagestyle{empty}
    \pgfplotstableset{
    col sep=semicolon,
    string type,
    trim cells,
    header=has colnames,
    skip coltypes=true,
    font={\small},
%
    after row={
    },
%
    every head row/.style={
        before row={
            \rowfont{\bfseries}
            \tabucline[1pt]{-}
        },
        after row={
            \tabucline[0.2pt]{-}
            \endhead
        }
    },
%
    every first row/.append style={
        before row={
            \tabucline[1pt]{-}
            \endfoot
        },
    },
}
%
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
date;       grade
2016-01-01; A
2016-01-15; B
2016-01-01; A
2016-01-15; B
2016-01-01; A
2016-01-15; B
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{17.6cm}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{}|X[p]|c|@{}},
    end table=\end{longtabu},
    %   
    columns={
        date,
        grade},
    %
    columns/date/.style={
        column name={\makecell{Date\\Datum}}},
    columns/grade/.style={
        column name={\makecell{Grade\\Známka}}},
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

Any help or suggestion how to correctly define longtable header/footer or what else is wrong with my code??

Thank you very much in advance for any help or suggestion!

Best regards,

Lubos