# Pgfplotstable and longtable page break problem

Tags: longtable, pgfplotstable

I have asked simmilar question ([Pgfplotstable using longtabu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372714/pgfplotstable-using-longtabu)), but unforunately with no answer/solution...

There is most simple (but for me still important) example I can provide:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotstableset{
    col sep=semicolon,
    string type,
    trim cells,
    header=has colnames,
    skip coltypes=true,
     every head row/.append style={
        after row=\endhead},
     every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
date;       grade
2016-01-01; \textbf{A}
2016-01-15; B
2016-01-01; A
2016-01-15; B
2016-01-01; A
2016-01-15; B
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}    
\vspace*{19.7cm}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    begin table=\begin{longtable}{@{}|c|c|@{}},
    end table=\end{longtable},
    columns={%
        date,
        grade},
    columns/date/.style={column name={Date}},
    columns/grade/.style={column name={Grade}},
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to define longtable header/footer inside pgfplotstable environment to avoid "duplicated header" showed in this exaplmple??

Thank you VERY much in advance for any help or suggestion!!

Best regards,

Lubos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really a pgfplotstable problem. You can get it with a simple longtable too when the start of the table is near the bottom of the page:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{19.7cm}

%\Needspace{4\baselineskip} 
\begin{longtable}{@{}|c|c|@{}}
date;       grade\endhead
2016-01-01; A\\
2016-01-15; B\\
2016-01-01; A\\
2016-01-15; B\\
2016-01-01; A\\
2016-01-15; B
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use e.g. \Needspace to force a page break before the table.